# Has a political campaign ever been "suspended", only to go on and later win the election?

Tags: united-states, election, campaigning

As a follow up to [Why do primaries contestants (usually) announce that they are "suspending" their campaign when they exit it?](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/50587/why-do-primaries-contestants-usually-announce-that-they-are-suspending-their) - are there examples of politicians initially "suspending" their campaign, but later "unfreezing" it and proceeding to win the election?  John McCain [famously suspended his campaign](https://www.usnews.com/news/campaign-2008/articles/2008/09/24/mccain-suspends-campaign-shocks-republicans) for two days in 2008, but he went on to lose to Obama in the subsequent election.

For the purposes of this question, both primaries and regular elections count. So a candidate "suspending" their primary campaign and later becoming the party's nominee would also count.

Comment: I assumed you meant US elections. "Suspending" is mostly a US convention in this regard.

Answer (score 5):

When Reagan died in June 2004, [Kerry and Bush suspended their campaigns.](https://www.theguardian.com/world/2004/jun/08/uselections2004.usa) Both won their respective primary elections and George W Bush ended up re-elected.

Comment: Please try to add references to support your answer.